# Copy text from within the batch file to a new text file

Tags: batch-file, copy

i am trying to copy the line below to a new text file using batch file. The line is given below

objIEA.Navigate "http://"&WScript.Arguments(0)&"/video?session=3&alphabet=83&channel="&WScript.Arguments(1)&"&profile="& WScript.Arguments(2)

This is the line. what i did is something like this and i am getting error.

ECHO objIEA.Navigate "http://"&WScript.Arguments(0)&"/video?session=3&alphabet=83&channel="&WScript.Arguments(1)&"&profile="& WScript.Arguments(2) > test.txt

THe above command is giving me error. I want to copy the exact line shown above to a new file and in reality the new file will have .vbs  extension. i mean the new file in reality should be test.vbs  but it is not working for even test.txt

please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to escape with ^ all the special characters like & < > | to prevent being interpreted by the command processor **EDIT:** but don't escape them inside quotes.

in your case, try this

```
ECHO objIEA.Navigate "http://"^&WScript.Arguments(0)^&"/video?session=3&alphabet=83&channel="^&WScript.Arguments(1)^&"&profile="^& WScript.Arguments(2)
```

Comment: But don't escape them inside quotes

Comment: This one worked. You just had extra ^ after 3 and 83. thank you very much